# Custom data request in Freebase provider for FSharp.Data

Tags: f#, freebase, f#-data

I'm using the FSharp.Data dll and it's pretty cool, but I have found some limitations and maybe someone knows how to make. I'm trying to retrieve some data from this page freebase page of [London](https://www.freebase.com/m/04jpl#) and with the provider is easey to access to the Travel Destination data of the place like  this:

```
let Extract mid =let freebaseContext = FreebaseDataWithKey.GetDataContext()
                 let place = freebaseContext.Commons.Travel.``Travel destinations``.Where(     fun x-> x.MachineId = mid) |> Seq.toList
```

This is great, but, since London isn't only a Travel Destination ( it is also a Dated Location, a filming location...) To extract this data I have to go to each collection of the provider and search for it. For example if I want to know wich sports teams are in Londond I would have to make a request again like this:

```
let sports = freebaseContext.Commons.Sports.``Sports Team Locations``.Where( fun x-> x.MachineId = mid) |> Seq.toList |> Seq.head
                 let teams = sports.Teams.ToList();
```

And so to each and every data property I want to access, this is very expensive since I have to make a lot of requests to the server and it's very easy to exceed the request-limit in google. Is there any way, to make the provider retrieve all the data from that page in only one request? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have very custom needs, you can try to use the functionality in [FreebaseRuntime](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Freebase/FreebaseRuntime.fs) directly, though it's not documented